# Does SpecsFor work with MSTest?

Tags: c#, mstest, bdd

The [SpecsFor](http://specsfor.com/) Behavior-Driven Development framework for .NET comes packaged with and apparently leverages NUnit.

I like the way MSTest is integrated into Visual Studio but I'm also interested in SpecFor's approach for spec testing.

So the question is:

Is SpecsFor compatible with MSTest? Does it require NUnit?

Comment: Looking through the source it's heavily integrated with `NUnit` so no luck here. You can use some commercial test runners like TDD.Net or Resharper to have a similar test runner exprerience (I think much better then MSTest) inside VS with `NUnit`.

Comment: I have Resharper, so it sounds good. In fact I suppose you just provided the answer, could as well post it as one to get the credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [source](https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/SpecsFor) of `SpecsFor` it's heavily integrated with `NUnit` so I am afraid but there is no easy way to use with `MSTest`.

However you can use one of the commercial test runners like [TDD.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) or [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) to have a similar test runner experience inside VS with `NUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

please visit below link, you will get your answer:

https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/SpecsFor/issues/86

Thanks.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.